# php form not sending email

Tags: php, forms, email

I am using a php script to send an email to a given address, however no email is being sent, even though the script is sending the user to the thank you page. It was working at one stage, but then inexplicably stopped.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
<?php

$to = "emailaddress@gmail.com \r\n";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$email_from = 'email@mydomain.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Contact via the website";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message\n\n\n".

$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: http://domain.com/thank-you/');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
 $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: So ,Whats is the error ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#101588

Comment: `even though the script is sending the user to the thank you page` its because you haven't checked the mail is sent or not. You just simply used `header()` function. `mail` function returns bool use with `if` statement and check.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting any error.The mail function returns true if the mail is send successfully and returns false if it doesnot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
```

- `$email_from` isn't yet defined, maybe you've got error here?
- Don't forget to enable `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` to see all errors, also check logs on server to see where's problem, maybe mail cannot be send by SMTP server or something...